# I want to locate and acess to my page http://myprestashopurl.com/en/login

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I want to acess and modify the users/login page, i've created a page for registration and i want to link it with prestashop in login page (when a user want to create an account he should be reirected to my link ), but i can't locate the folder to modify

expect to redirect to my link where the user want to create an account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the href attribute of the link to create an account in `templates/customer/authentication.tpl`

```
{block name='page_footer'}
  <div class="no-account">
    <a href="{$urls.pages.register}" data-link-action="display-register-form">
        {l s='No account? Create one here' d='Shop.Theme.Customeraccount'}
    </a>
  </div>
{/block}
```

Become

```
{block name='page_footer'}
  <div class="no-account">
    <a href="http://myprestashopurl.com/en/login" data-link-action="display-register-form">
        {l s='No account? Create one here' d='Shop.Theme.Customeraccount'}
    </a>
  </div>
{/block}
```